# Set activity launch mode programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I need to call activity with different `launchMode` according to my app state. In one case it should be `singleInstance`, in other - `singleTask`. I know how to set `launchMode` in **AndroidManifest**, but since it should be dynamic property I have to do it from code. I thought, that I can add some specific flag to intent, before starting activity, but I found only `singleTop` flag. So is any way to solve this issue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigations I've noticed that it is impossible to do that in such way. But good news is that i've got some workaround:

You have to create two `Activities`, each with corresponding **launchModes**. 
One `Activity` is real `Activity` with your code inside, and another one will just call main `Activity` in `onCreate()` method, but since it will have needed **launchMode**, main `Activity` will be launched with that mode. Not very nice, but completely working solution.

After that, instead of trying open your `Activity` with intent flags, put in intent `class` of the `Activity` according to **launchMode** you need.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I need two different launchMode related to different android API level:
in AndroidManifest

```
android:launchMode="@integer/launchModeAPIlevel"
```

and different integers value inside folders values-18, values-21

```
<integer name="launchModeAPIlevel">1</integer>
```

launchmode 1 == singleTop 
singleTask == 2

Comment: Is this working? launchMode expects a string correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just create two Activities A and B, B extends A.
In manifest declare launchMode="singleTask" for A, and launchMode="singleInstance" for B.
And start the Activity according to launchMode you need.