# How to set different - 2 configChanges for one android activity in android manifest file or any other way

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

Different configChanges for different android os version for single activity

```
   <activity
            android:name=".Activity_JoinMeeting"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|locale"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
```

configChanges for android OS 23 I want set set 4 properties and configChanges for android OS above 23 I want set 2 properties
how can I achive it

Answer (score 1):

You can define two different activity in AndroidManifest file one for above android api 23 and other for rest android apis.

and launch that activies after checking api,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

}
```

Comment: I don't want to create two different activity

Comment: to achieve this functionality you have to define two different activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the answer of aorlondo in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155526/set-activity-launch-mode-programmatically) and maybe try this solution with each properties you want to change.